# Is it possible to change variable while I'm sending it?

Tags: c#

I mean

```
double x=5;
double k=Func(x+3.5,h+1.2);//I send x=8.5
double y=x;//x=5;
```

I want to change it when I send it.

```
double x=5;
double k=Func(x+3.5,h+1.2);
double y=x;//x=8.5
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: What about `h`? You seem to be declaring a `double h` and then taking that `h` and adding `1.2` before calling the method.

Comment: It my mistake. not h but `k=Func(..);` h- another parameter. If it somehow possible to change x I'll use the same method on h.

Comment: Your comments and code **do not agree**. The question is tagged C#, but yet there are pointers used below? Unlikely... (Smells like C/C++, but could be "unsafe"). Please post *full code* and *error messages*, including that of `Func` into the question, and verify the tags.

Answer (score 3):

**Please don't do this.** Yes. That's my answer.

It is, however, *possible* because assignment statements *with side-effects by definition* can be used as expressions. I have removed the extra code that didn't seem to apply.

```
void Func (double _x) {
    // do nothing
    // _x = 8.5 when invoked from below
}
double x = 5;
Func(x = x + 3.5);  // or Func(x += 3.5)
// x = 8.5
```

The above is [almost always] *much* better written with the assignment -- and thus side-effect -- kept separately from the function call itself: (In *most* cases, both forms have identical semantics.)

```
x += 3.5;
Func(x);
```

Happy coding.

---

If you *do* wish to use `out`/`ref`, keep in mind that *it only makes sense to use variables as the `out`/`ref` parameters*: the expression `x + 3.5` is not a variable -- it *cannot* be assigned to -- and is thus unsuitable. (I believe VB.NET also allows properties.)

```
void Add(ref double _y, double s) {
    // _y = 5
    _y += s;
    // _y = 8.5
}
double y = 5;
Add(ref y, 3.5);
// y = 8.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
double x=5;
double k=Func(x+=3.5,h+1.2);
double y=x;//x should be 8.5
```

This way `x` evaluates to 8.5 before the function is called.

But, may I ask why the need to do this?

Comment: I call function1, then change values h,x. Then I call function2, then change values h,x. Then I call function3, then change values h,x. So it will be 7 lines.But When I change values in function' call I need only 3 lines.

Comment: If you are just trying to cut on the lines then my answer should be enough. But, if you're also looking for changing the value of the variables **inside** the function, you should take a look at Adel Boutros answer. Keep in mind that fewer lines don't always translate to "nicer" code, changing the value of a variable inside a function call can make the code a little bit more difficult to "read".

Comment: If my function is `func(double *a,double *b)` and I have got a method `gets(double *x,double *y)` with call inside `double alha=func(*x+h/2,*y+h/3)` why I always get errors?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand pointers yet. If you're not trying to change the value of variables inside the function then you don't need pointers, get rid of all the `*`'s and take a look at my answer. If you do need pointers then I suggest you to read more here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/usingpointers10022007082330AM/usingpointers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are passing the x variable by copy not by reference. This is why x is still 5 after your functions finishes. You should change your function h from:
`h(int x, int y)`

to

```
h(int * x, int *y)
```

**EDIT :**

With pointers you pass the variable x and do all your operations on it. With no pointers, the function creates a copy of the variable x and works on it then destroys it when the functions ends. So the real x is not modified.

Pointers and references work together. You declare the function with pointers and pass the variables with reference